# zip from other location

Tags: command-line, zip

i need to zip my directory from other location

```
/a/b/c $ zip -r x.zip /tmp/w/x
```

creates the entire path in zip, when i unzip

```
unzip x.zip
```

It creates `/tmp/w/` also in current folder, i don't want that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you just want `x`,

```
file="$PWD/x.zip"
(cd /tmp/w;zip -r "$file" x)
```

does the job in a subshell. When the subshell exits, the `cd` wears off.